# ADP API Update Worker Information

Tags: post, postman, worker, adp-api

I am trying to make updates within the ADP Worker API, though I keep getting "403: Invalid Scope" for the error. I am using [this reference guide](https://developers.adp.com/articles/guides/worker-management-api-guide-for-adp-workforce-now?chapter=4), specifically the People > Personal Information > Personal Profile > Contact > Add Home Phone section.

I can interact with the API through GET requests, though I am unable to POST. I am using the URL:

https://api.adp.com/events/hr/v1/worker.personal-communication.landline.add

**Body Payload:**

```
{
"events": [
{
  "data": {
    "eventContext": {
      "worker": {
        "associateOID": "exampleID123123"
      }
    },
    "transform": {
      "worker": {
        "person": {
          "communication": {
            "landline": {
              "areaDialing": "240",
              "dialNumber": "4567896"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "links": []
}
]
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
"response": {
    "responseCode": 403,
    "methodCode": "POST",
    "resourceUri": {
        "href": "/events/hr/v1/worker.personal-communication.landline.add"
    },
    "serverRequestDateTime": "2021-09-09T18:26:44.607Z",
    "applicationCode": {
        "code": 403,
        "typeCode": "error",
        "message": "Invalid Scope"
    },
    "client_ip_adddress": "xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx",
    "adp-correlationID": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
}
}
```

**Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I believe the answer to my initial question is that we are required to contact our ADP representative to add the ability to hit the Event API. We only had access to the Worker API, which allowed successful calls previously.

[image: From the API Docs]

Comment: The above screenshot is from https://developers.adp.com/articles/general/api-common-exceptions-and-tips-for-handling in case you were wondering (as I was).